# python requests: easy way to replace http get request argument?

Tags: python, http, get, python-requests

I have a http GET request like so:

```
url = 'www.somedomain.com/content?var=whatever&pageno=1'
r = requests.get(url)
```

I'd like to replace `pageno=1` with `pageno=2`, they say `requests` are for humans, but I couldn't figure out how to do this without parsing the query into a pyhton dictionary using `urlparse`, then change the corresponding value, then `urllib.urlencode` into a new query.

### Notice

I know I can probably do a `re.sub()` and solve the problem in 2 or 3 lines, I just think there must be a 'pythonic way'.

I've been using `scrapy` in the past few months and they got a nice `Request.replace` method to do this, think I'm gonna suggest a feature to `requests`.

Comment: so you already figured out how to do this. I would definitely recommend the `urlparse`/`urlencode` method over regex, unless you have to do thousands of them in a loop in which case I guess you ought to try different ways and benchmark them

Comment: Note the separation of concerns: `requests` is for making requests, it doesn't need to provide URL parsing functionality when the standard library already provides that.

Comment: Well requests does have the [params](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) argument that can probably help make it a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `params` argument of the `get()` method. This functionality is described in the [quick start](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

```
>>> payload = {'var': 'whatever', 'pageno': '1'}
>>> r = requests.get("http://www.somedomain.com/content", params=payload)
>>> print(r.url)
http://www.somedomain.com/content?var=whatever&pageno=1
```

Using this method of passing parameters, you can easily manipulate the `payload` dictionary prior to calling `.get()`

Comment: For anyone coming here from a web search result, specifying the `params` argument does not replace existing arguments of the same key.  If the example URL were instead `http://www.somedomain.com/content?var=bababooey`, you'd get both values of `var` in your query string.

Whether that is useful or annoying depends on your use-case... sometimes APIs meaningfully understand multiple instances of the same parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I always do it the simple way - though there are always multiple way to do the same thing.

First use some logic to make script find the max no. of pages and then,

```
max_page=10 # You need to find a way to get this, for now assuming its 10 for example purpose
current_page=0
while current_page!=max_page:
    current_page=current_page+1
    url = 'www.somedomain.com/content?var=whatever&pageno=%s'%str(current_page)
    r = requests.get(url)
```